# Changing an application from Program Files(x86) to Program Files will forces Windows to run it on 64 mode?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, services

(this is not a duplicatted thread from [Is it OK to install 32 bit programs in "Program Files" on 64 bit windows instead of "Program Files (x86)?](https://superuser.com/questions/164135/is-it-ok-to-install-32-bit-programs-in-program-files-on-64-bit-windows-instead) im considering that im doing a question looking for another answear)

So, i need to recompile my code to x64 plataform or, if i change the app path Windows will work on it with 64 bits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, a 64bit executable is a 64bit executable is a 64bit executable. The two separate directories exist to make it easier to maintain a 32 bit and 64 bit copy of an application, as far as I can tell.

You will need to recompile your things for 64bit, as the location of an executable makes no difference to how it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to recompile a 32 to 64 windows driver you will need to do the same for a application, all variables from your code will need to readapt to the new 64 reality.